# Changing the Team setting of an iOS project at build time

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to be able to change the Team used for code signing an iOS target at build time, using a configuration, build variable or similar mechanism.  As far as I can tell, the only way to access the Team setting is via the dropdown in the target's "General" configuration tab, and it is stored in the project file.  Right now, I have created a second target with another team set, which is a lot of duplicated settings to just change this one parameter.

Is there a more flexible way to control the Team setting?

Comment: Found a solution to this? I'm looking to change the Team and Build Settings using command line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using shell scripting by changing the `DevelopmentTeam` variable in your `.pbxproj` file. Simply fetch the current team using -

`awk -F '=' '/DevelopmentTeam/ {print $2; exit}' project.pbxproj`

Replace that using `sed` with your new development team replacing its 10-digit certificate id.

`sed -i '' 's/old_team_cert_id/new_team_cert_id/g' project.pbxproj`

Comment: Works for me.  `sed` may be useful for making other changes in the project as well; I had forgotten about old-school Unix tools.

Comment: Yes, `awk` and `sed` can be easily used to replace other parts in the project as well.

Comment: this is now `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM`