# Xcode 14: how to quickly update signing for multuple internal cocoapods frameworks?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, codesign, xcode14

So I've switched to Xcode 14, and it gave me a lot of compile errors, most of them were related to signing the internal frameworks (the app is well-modularized).
While I've been doing that manually (updating about 70 modules), I felt bad as it's a waste of time, and the problem can happen again in the future.

I've found this thread where `CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual` is mentioned, but `grep CODE_SIGN_STYLE -r .` in a project folder gave me a lot `CODE_SIGN_STYLE = Automatic;` hits. Also, the checkbox `Automatically manage signing` is enabled for all of those modules.
[image]

I guess it's Xcode14 bug, so all I wanted to ask:

1. How have you solved this problem in case you've met it?
2. Could I use some non-custom script like `xcodesign-fix-team-for-automatic-signing --team MY_TEAM_ID` to do it in 1 click?

---

UPD: I've found such strings in `project.pbxproj` files those "broken" modules:

```
                "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=appletvos*]" = "";
                "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "";
                "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=watchos*]" = "";
```

But after I manually update the `Team` in Signing tab, that `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]` value is still empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution which worked for me](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11402#issuecomment-1149585364) (just added that phase to `Podfile`):

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings["DEVELOPMENT_TEAM"] = " Your Team ID  "
         end
    end
  end
end
```

I've found it in the CocoaPods issue, which is identical to my problem.

Before that, I tried to find `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM`/`DevelopmentTeam`/`Team` in the `.pbxproj` files of individual modules using [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33699696). But as there was no team specified, it became obvious that this is a CocoaPods issue.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without specifing the team id.
Good for generic copy-paste.

```
post_install do |installer|
    # get team-id from project's first target
    dev_team = ""
    project = installer.aggregate_targets[0].user_project
    project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            if dev_team.empty? and !config.build_settings['DEVELOPMENT_TEAM'].nil?
                dev_team = config.build_settings['DEVELOPMENT_TEAM']
                break
            end
        end
    end
  
    # Apply team-id
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings["DEVELOPMENT_TEAM"] = dev_team
        end
    end
end
```

Inspired from: https://www.jianshu.com/p/685b32c3d521